# Juego del ahorcado sólo se permiten letras mayúsculas

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que hacer el juego del ahorcado en código y estoy estancado en una parte a ver si me pueden dar una mano.

```js
//Función para reemplazar el caracter por la letra
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) { return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length); }

let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];

let palabra = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random()*palabras.length)];

//Reemplazo la palabra por guiones
let palabraConGuiones = palabra.replace(/./g, "_ ");

let contadorFallos = 0;

document.querySelector('#salida00').innerHTML = palabraConGuiones;


var letra00 = document.getElementById('letra00').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
});

document.querySelector('#boton00').addEventListener('click',function(){
   
    let letra = letra00.document.querySelector('#letra00').value;
    

    let haFallado = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++){
        
        if(letra == palabra[i]){
            
            //i*2 se debe a que la letra es reemplazada por 2 caracteres; un guión y un espacio.
            palabraConGuiones = palabraConGuiones.replaceAt(i*2, letra);
            
            haFallado = false;

        }
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="20" id="letra00">
 
<button id='boton00'>Evaluar letra</button>
 
<p id="salida00"></p>
```

Me funcionaba correctamente antes pero como requisito tengo que el programa sólo funcione con letras mayúsculas. Para eso cambie el array, cree la variable 'letra00' y la adicioné a 'letra', desde entonces me salta error.

Comment: Que esperabas guardar en `letra00`? Fíjate que ahora mismo estás guardando ahí el resultado de  un `addEventListener` que por [definición](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value) es `undefined`

Comment: Osea quería que la variable letra solo puedan ser ingresados letras mayúsculas pero me daba error cuando le ponía a let letra el .toUpperCase()

Comment: resultado de un addEventListener que por definición es undefined eso no sabía

Comment: podrias editar el codigo, te falta cerrar el query selector con '});' despues del click event.

Comment: ya lo edite perdón, es que el código sigue pero no quería ponerlo completo

Comment: Osea lo que busco es que en el input solo trabaje con letras mayusculas

Comment: por que usas letra00 para capturar el valor ? ---  let letra = letra00.document.querySelector('#letra00').value;

Comment: ya lo corregí, ahora anda. muchas gracias Frnk y Federico

Comment: Por favor, no destruyas la pregunta. Pon la solución como respuesta, incluso vas a recibir votos positivos y la puedes marcar como aceptada. Ya devolví la pregunta a su estado anterior para ayudarte

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo ahí lo hice tal cual me indicaste

Answer (score 0):

Como me indicaron en los comentarios mi error estaba en la variable let letra00 (la cual no puede contener un addEventListener). La forma correcta es:

```
document.getElementById('letra00').addEventListener('keyup', function(){

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()

});



let letra = document.querySelector('#letra00').value.toUpperCase();
```

Gracias a los que comentaron!.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.